# Connection times out while using scp

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssh, scp

I am trying to download a file from a computer that I have connected with using ssh. I type into the terminal

```
scp /path/to/file <name of my computer>@192.168.0.15:home/desktop
```

This file isn't big (about 35 mb), but after typing this command literally nothing happens, and after some time such message appears:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.15 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

So, how can I fix it?

Comment: `scp /path/to/file <name of my computer>@192.168.0.15:/home/desktop`

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of scp is :

```
$ scp SOURCE DESTINATION
```

For example, if I want to copy a file named **foo** in my home directory to the home directory of a remote machine **192.168.0.15**, running ssh server, the syntax would be:

```
$ scp /home/john/foo luther@192.168.0.15:/home/luther/
```

where luther is a username on 192.168.0.15

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of the syntaxe of your scp command ?
Try :

```
scp /path/to/file 192.168.0.15:.
```

You can also check /var/log/syslog file of the 198.168.0.15 server, to check your connection

Answer (score 0):

There can sometimes be firewall issues. If having a terminal open on your computer and listing the source as from the ssh server won't work, try opening a terminal on the ssh server and setting the destination to your local computer. In other words, try SENDING it from the ssh server instead of BRINGING it from there, or vice versa. Does that make sense? This often fixes the issue for me.